# Configure an ADSL Router to connect to the internet via a DSLAM, then Squid Proxy

Tags: internet, squid, dsl, adsl-router

I have a setup as follows

```
PC <-- ADSL Router <-- DSLAM <-- SquidProxy Server <--> ISP Provided Router --> Internet
```

1. The Squid proxy (running on Ubuntu 12.04) connects to the ISP Router via `eth0` and is configured to get DHCP IP's in the `192.168.1.0/24` range. The Router's default gateway being `192.168.1.1`.
2. The Squid proxy connects to the DSLAM via `eth1` (which is given a static IP `192.168.2.1`). `eth1` is also configured as a dhcp out with the ip range `192.168.2.50-192.168.2.210`, and DNS' `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.8.4`.
3. The DSLAM ethernet port facing the squid proxy is assigned a static IP in the `192.168.2.0/24` range. The port going to the ADSL Router is also assigned a static IP in a different range (e.g. `192.168.3.0/24`), as is the ADSL router.

With the above setup, what settings should I give the ADSL router? Especially the

- Default Gateway
- DNS Server IP

Comment: I have no idea on which case this setup could be used. Who hosts its own DSLAM ? is that homework from a xDSL course ?

Comment: Well, quite worthy of that. But it's very much a real world setup. Thing is, it's too costly to use fiber, and too far apart to use utp.

Answer (score 0):

So after much deliberation, and since it would have been too much trouble to re-configure each ADSL router, I did the following.

1. Did no changes to the DSLAM and ADSL router (which still had the default IP as  192.168.1.1).
2. Changed the config of the ISP router, by replacing the 192.168.1.1 ip of the router with 192.168.2.1.
3. Changed the 'eth0' adapter on the proxy to DHCP (Now it receives DHCP ip in 192.168.2.0/24) and gave the 'eth1' adapter a static IP of 192.168.1.1
4. Changed the WAN and LAN ip ranges of the squid proxy to reflect those of eth1 and eth0 respectively.

And that's it! After that all I had to do was to have the end users enter the eth1 ip of 192.168.1.1/24 as the proxy ip and it works!!
One problem that occurred to me a bit late was that when the proxy server receives packets via the ADSL router and DSLAM, the MAC address received is not that of the PC that sent it, so I am unable to implement a MAC (or IP based) filter on such users. 
Still not figured out how to get around that...